# WebDriver randomly closes connection during screenshot

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webpage-screenshot

I don't know exactly how to replicate this error, but I do a lot of screenshots of the pages with WebDriver. Sometimes, suddenly I get this exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9958
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '*******-*******', ip: '***.***.*.**', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: ExtendedWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getScreenshotAs(RemoteWebElement.java:392)
    ...
```

I don't quit/close the driver before that happens, and previous commands right before `getScreenshotAs` work as expected. It only happens with `getScreenshotAs` command. Never had this problem with any other. It's very rare though. I had this error maybe 20-30 in total. For example I run tests all night, then in 3 nights I get this error once.

Is this a known issue? I'm using `ChromeDriver` most of the times.

---

I didn't specify any related code, because it happens regardless. I use stock version of ChromeDriver and selenium java library both version `3.141.59`.

Comment: Which version of Chrome and ChromeDriver are you using? The exact versions of each can make a big difference.

Comment: Does the system goes into sleep?